# is Firefox .deb package in ubuntu 22.04 in beta?

Tags: firefox, ppa, snap, repository, deb

i have replaced firefox snap package by `.deb` one in ubuntu 22.04.
i am using this repository for firefox `.deb` package: `ppa:mozillateam/ppa`

two days ago it gets update to version 100. but in windows 11, it is still in version 99.0.1.

i can remember that in past ubuntu was a little behind windows in updating firefox.

So, i am curious about this update, is it beta version?

I checked firefox's about page and it does not mention `beta`.

Also, Is there any modification on firefox snap verion which is not available in `.deb` package any more?

Comment: Ask the PPA maintainers. In Ubuntu the version is still 99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu does not anymore provide Firefox as a .deb package. So there is no answer to the question that you reflected in your title.

You indicated that you added the mozillateam ppa. The description of that PPA has not been updated and reads

> Mozilla Team's Firefox 91 ESR and Thunderbird 91 or 78 stable builds

although we know that nowadays, also the regular Firefox is nowadays provided. Currently, indeed, it is at version 100.0, although the download section on the Firefox website still publishes the 99.0.1 version.

Mozilla has a dedicated PPA for beta versions: `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next`, where version numbers have a "b" appended. It can be assumed that the version in `ppa:mozillateam`, which is designed to have builds of stable versions, is at least kind of a Release Candidate quality. That version then indeed is bleeding edge, and it can be expected that 100 will roll out via the website very soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can download latest official .deb build working with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) here:
[https://launchpad.net/~phd/+archive/ubuntu/firefox/](https://launchpad.net/%7Ephd/+archive/ubuntu/firefox/)

This is a PPA repository with official Ubuntu packages released originally for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal) and updated automatically as soon as a new version is released.

Comment: This is not answering the question whether the firefox package in ppa:mozillateam/ppa is beta or not.